# How do you convert a dataframe of datetime to time only? Basically removing the date element in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Timestamp Dataframe Picture]

I want to compare two dataframes with time objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processing all columns:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.dt.time)
```

But times are pure python objects, so not easy processing in pandas.

Possible solution should be convert times to timedeltas:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x.dt.strtime('%H:%M:%S')))
```